# MongoDB, AngularJS : Return multiple error messages

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose we have **2 required** properties`title` and `content`

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Title cannot be blank'
},
  content: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Content cannot be blank'
},
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
});
```

At the moment, when I call the $save function, the server stops after the first error and returns a string with 'Title cannot be blank'. Is there a way to let mongoose return a JSON object of **all** failed validations?

```
    // Create new Article
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Article object
        var article = new Articles({
            title: this.title,
            content: this.content
        });

        // Redirect after save
        article.$save(function(response) {
            //success
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            //Desired output
            // errors :{
            //   "Title" : "Title cannot be blank",
            //   "Content" : "Content cannot be blank"}
        });
    };
```

Is the issue on the server-side (should I tweak Mongoose model?) or on the client-side (should I tweak Angular $save function's errorResponse?) ?

EDIT: a screenshot of the errorResponse object : [image: console.dir(errorResponse)]

Comment: What does errorResponse.errors output?  Can you console.dir that?

Comment: Does this make sense to do that, in general? Say, I have title required and content's length > title's length. If title is empty, how are you gonna validate against content (if I passed in a string)?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the errorResponse object. It does not hold an errors property. ABOS, yes it does make sense, you can just add an if condition for when title is empty

Answer (score 0):

This is a roundabout way since mongoose cannot do this for you.

```
// Create new Article
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Article object
        var article = new Articles({
            title: this.title,
            content: this.content
        });

    for (i=0; i=number_of_validations;i++){

            // Redirect after save
            article.$save(function(response) {
                //success
        break;
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            if (error == 'Title cannot be...'){
            article.title = "Will be deleted";
            }
            else if (error == 'Content cannot...'){
            article.content = "Will be deleted"
            }
           else // other checks {
            }
            errors.push(error);
             //Desired output
            // errors :{
            //   "Title" : "Title cannot be blank",
            //   "Content" : "Content cannot be blank"}
            });
    }
    if (errors.length != 0){
        article.$remove....//remove article from DB
        console.log(errors);
    }
    };
```

Comment: does mongoose still have still problem ?